# Testing iCloud outside XCode : Signature invalid

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, icloud

So, I am working on a Mac application, with iCloud feature.  Within Xcode, everything is fine.  I am using the Mac developer certificate paired with the Mac team profile (code signing identity, from build setting).  When I compile and run, I can save/load files from iCloud.  I am happy.

Where I am not happy, this is when I create the package and send it to the testers.  The application is not starting at all!  I have the following output from the console :

```
12-02-13 3:50:09.796 PM sandboxd: ([51185]) taskgated-helper(51185) deny mach-lookup com.apple.ocspd
12-02-13 3:50:09.796 PM sandboxd: ([51185]) taskgated-helper(51185) deny mach-lookup com.apple.ocspd
12-02-13 3:50:09.796 PM sandboxd: ([51185]) taskgated-helper(51185) deny mach-lookup com.apple.ocspd
12-02-13 3:50:09.797 PM sandboxd: ([51185]) taskgated-helper(51185) deny mach-lookup com.apple.ocspd
12-02-13 3:50:09.867 PM ReportCrash: Saved crash report for myAppName[51195] version ??? (???) to /Users/plboily/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/myAppName_2012-02-13-155009_Blinky.crash
12-02-13 3:50:09.870 PM ReportCrash: Removing excessive log: file://localhost/Users/plboily/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/myAppName_2012-02-03-113847_Blinky.crash
12-02-13 3:50:10.000 PM kernel: CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x1000): p=51195[myAppName ] honoring CS_KILL, final status 0x10201
12-02-13 3:50:10.000 PM kernel: CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x1000): p=51195[myAppName ] clearing CS_VALID
```

The following is a snippet of the crash log :

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   dyld                            0x8fea9280 dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*,  int, char const**, long, macho_header const*) + 526
1   dyld                            0x8fea9063 _dyld_start + 51
```

Any idea what's wrong?
Anybody know why i have these problems?  I already have my Mac team profile in my system profile

By the way, when I do build on our build machine, there is a _*CodeSignature* folder appearing into the .app folder, plus an *embedded.provisioningprofile* file.  Everything seems to be there.  I am wondering if I do have to add the code signing identity to ALL targets of my project?  Right now, i only signed the application target.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what was my problem!

The problem is that after my codesign command, I modified my binary, with change_name_tool.  So, because the binary changed, the signature was not valid anymore!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to change my entitlement.plist to have the app profile id not $(TEAMID).appid so go too dev center look at the app id and get the letters and numbers before the dns part of your app id and replace $(TEAMID) in entitlement.plist to that. I did this and the same error you had stopped but I only had to do it with one app not the 2 other iCloud apps I have. I also deleted all doc in icloud to start with  clean storage .

```
- (NSURL *)iCloudURL
{
    return [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
}
    NSError *error = nil;
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:[self iCloudURL] error:&error];
```